# Is android kernel same for all devices

Tags: rom, kernel

I m newbie to building roms. I have Hiawei G630 device with 4.3 kernel. My question is would it work if I use Samsung or other Huawei kernel. 
Sorry form my bad english

Answer (score 1):

No, kernels are device specific and contain a lot of code (not only open source Android code, but much proprietary as well) that is compiled specifically for a devices hardware.

There exists a generic Android kernel, but it lacks many features like telephony and such, so device manufacturers have to add proper code that fits their hardware.

**So:** No, you can't use a Samsung kernel on a Huawei device or vice versa because of the hardware modules of each individual device.